# Error defining a defining a function where its input is a file and has an nls fit: "Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level"

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, nls

I'm trying to fit a set of data to an error function. I successfully using the following code:

```
erf <- function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1
data <- read.csv("z0.csv")
x<-data[,1]
y<-data[,2]
y<-y-min(y)
y<-y/max(y)
x<-x[which.max(y):which.min(y)]
x<-(x-min(x))/7200
y<-y[which.max(y):which.min(y)]
m<-nls(y~a/2*(1-erf((sqrt(2)*(x-b))/c)),start=list(a=1,b=0,c=0.001))
r<-summary(m)$coefficients[3,1]
dr<-summary(m)$coefficients[3,2]
```

The steps in between are meant to normalize my data in order to make my maximum value of y one and my minimum zero; to use certain data for the fit; and to make a conversion for the x vales.

Since I have to do this same procedure for with a lot of files, I made the following function:

```
radius <- function(file) {
  data <- read.csv(file = paste0(file, ".csv")
  x<-data[,1]
  y<-data[,2]
  y<-y-min(y)
  y<-y/max(y)
  x<-x[which.max(y):which.min(y)]
  x<-(x-min(x))/7200
  y<-y[which.max(y):which.min(y)]
  m<-nls(y~a/2*(1-erf((sqrt(2)*(x-b))/c)),start=list(a=1,b=0,c=0.001))
  c<-summary(m)$coefficients[3,1]
  return(c)
}
```

But I get the following errors:
Error: unexpected symbol in:

- Error: unexpected symbol in:
  "  data <- read.csv(file = paste0(file, ".csv")
  x"
- Error in nls(y ~ a/2 * (1 - erf((sqrt(2) * (x - b))/c)), start =
  list(a = 1,  :    number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
- Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
- Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `read.csv` function is missing a closing paranthesis `)`